# Android: setRefreshing(false) on DDP callback hangs app

Tags: android, meteor, refresh, swiperefreshlayout, ddp

Here is the code:

```
 public void onRefresh() {
    MyDDPState.getInstance().getItems(null, new DDPListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Map<String, Object> json) {

            Log.d(TAG, "refreshed");
            if (json.get("result") == null) {
/*
 * Result is null action
 */
                Log.d(TAG, "Null");
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                return;
            }
            List<Map<String, Object>> temp = (ArrayList) json.get("result");
            Log.d(TAG, temp.toString());
            MyDDPState.getInstance().initItems(temp);

            Log.d(TAG, "converted" + MyDDPState.getInstance().getItems().toString());

            Log.d(TAG, swipeLayout.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "Finished refreshing");

            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            Log.d(TAG, "Refresh closed");
        }
    });

}
```

swipeLayout refers to a private variable in the class that holds the SwipeRefreshLayout. On the callback, I try to call setrefreshing(false) to get rid of the progress indicator, but this call hangs the async function. All the other Logs work except for the "Refresh closed" log.

For some reason, I think because of the library I'm using, errors inside DDP Listeners are not logged either, so I can't trace it. swipeLayout.setRefreshing when called outside of the DDP call work fine.

Comment: what does hang mean?

Comment: The async call kind of just stops running, or exits.

Comment: does the application crash?

Comment: It doesn't crash, the async call just stops

Comment: I just tried adding a setRefreshing(false) call to the outside of the getItems call, and when I do this the callback passes through to Refresh closed

Comment: For clarity, the set refreshing call in onresult seems to work when its not actually changing the refreshing boolean

Comment: did you find the id using findViewById() of swipeLayout? and why are you calling setRefreshing(false) TWICE.

Comment: swipeLayout is initialized in onCreateView here

`swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        initRefreshListener();`

Comment: swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false) is inside your inner class new DDPListener() { .. This may be causing the problem!

Comment: When I do a log on swipeLayout, it show the correct layout, and when I do the call using findviewbyid I still get the same error.

What do you mean by the function call causing a problem there?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I managed to solve the issue.

When I tried to change a ui variable, the function would stop running.

Turns out the issue was that I was changing UI variables on the wrong thread. To fix it, you have to make the UI calls inside a ui thread by calling:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        /* 
         * UI code
         */
    }
});
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html